# Knockout binding with JQuery templating is not showing data?

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, knockout-2.0, jquery-templates

I m very new to Knockout and as a learning exercise I m trying to do knockout binding with JQuery templating (my apologies if I m referring wrong terms)

Please see this link: http://jsfiddle.net/Yawer/7xvgJ/1/

Here is my code:

JS:

```
  var data = [
    { Id: 1, Name: "Jim" },
    { Id: 2, Name: "Bilal" },
    { Id: 3, Name: "Hussain" },
    { Id: 4, Name: "Hassan" }
];

var viewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    //data
    self.tags = ko.observableArray(data);
    self.tagToAdd = ko.observable();

    //behaviour
    self.addTag = function () {
        self.tags.push({ Name: self.tagToAdd() });
    };

};

$(function () { 
    var vm = new viewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(vm);

});
```

HTML:

```
    <div data-bind="template: 'tagsTemp'">
</div>
<script id="tagsTemp" type="text/html">

        {{each tags}}

            <span>${Name}</span>



        {{/each}}

</script>
```

I m expecting list of names but instead of names I m getting code:

```
{{each tags}} ${Name} {{/each}}
```

Kindly guide me where I m wrong in code. I understand Knockout binding can be done in different ways but I need to do using Jquery template. Kindly help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First: you should not use the jquery.tmpl support because that library is no longer maintained. The native KO templating engine is sufficient for the 95% of the use cases.

Second: although KO supports jquery.tmpl out of the box you still need to reference the [jquery.tmpl library](https://github.com/BorisMoore/jquery-tmpl) itself.

From the [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html#note-6-using-jquerytmpl-an-external-string-based-template-engine):

> By default, Knockout comes with support for jquery.tmpl. To use it,
>   you need to reference the following libraries, in this order:
>
> ```
> <!-- First jQuery -->     <script src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
> <!-- Then jQuery.tmpl --> <script src="jquery.tmpl.js"></script>
> <!-- Then Knockout -->    <script src="knockout-x.y.z.js"></script>
> ```

Here is your [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nemesv/kF4j8/) with the missing reference added.